# Как исправить ошибку Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25) при импорте БД в phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь сделать импорт БД на VPS в phpmyadmin. Сделал с прошлой базы экспорт, теперь при импорте файла .sql бьет ошибку:
Найдено 1 ошибок при анализе.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL запрос: Изменить Изменить

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

Ответ MySQL: Документация

#2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Пробовал сделать импорт на open server, все пошло без проблем. Подскажите как можно исправить, кто сталкивался

Comment: А почему ON а не 1 или TRUE?

Comment: Я вообще не могу понять откуда он этот параметр берет и где его изменить

Comment: Возможно версии БД отличаются, и вероятно в какой то из версий параметр ON может быть не строковым, но имхо должно быть не ON а TRUE или 1

Comment: Окройте такстовым редактором дамп, и найдите через поиск. Затем поправьте ON на 1. Лучше эксперементировать с копией файла

Comment: Это косяк пых-админа. Нафиг его, используй нормальную SSL-консоль.